# C code to print the USB content

Tags: c, uefi

I am working in a UEFI environment and working with C code. To run a simple UEFI command I have to do it through C as shown below:

```
    swprintf(
             run_cmd,
             wcslen(L"idrac1:\\Tools\\TCP_Recieve.efi")+wcslen(ipAddress)+1,
             L"idrac1:\\Tools\\TCP_Recieve.efi %ls",
             ipAddress
            );
```

I need to know how to print the contents of the Pen Drive which is connected to my server using C code. I need something similar to 'ls' or 'dir' but for UEFI. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The UEFI Shell source is available, which contains the source code for the `ls` command.  It should give you enough information for what you need.

1. Download The [EDKII UEFI Shell source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edk2/files/EDK%20II%20Releases/EDK%20II%20Shell/EDKII_UEFI_Shell_2.0_ShellPkg_Rel_1.0.zip/download).
2. Locate \ShellPkg\Library\UefiShellLevel2CommandsLib\Ls.c.

Comment: Its not the function particularly that I need to write. ls command works so I could just send the command through my C code. The issue is to traverse to my usb location. I am very unfamiliar with UEFI and I am not able to traverse through UEFI to my pen drive.